# Inserting variable in echo function

Tags: php

I have have some php code that I can't get to work ...
I can't seem to find my mistake :/, I realize it's going to be a `syntax error` but after looking for an hour with no success I turn to you guys for help =)

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
    $t= number_latest_added();
    for ($n = 0; $n<$t; $n += 3) {
        $latest = latest($n);
        echo "<a class=\"example-image-link\" href=\"" .$latest. "\" data-lightbox=\"example-set\" data-title=\"De la galerie : " . $latest . "\"><div id=\"a\" style=\"background: url(" . $latest . ") 50% 50% / cover;background-size: contain;background-repeat: no-repeat;\"></div></a></br>";
    } 
?>
```

The problem is in getting the `echo` to concatenate with the variable but it isn't working ( the variable is echoed 3 times and then the text is echoed with blank instead of the variable)  and I don't understand why not ...
If somebody could help me see my error; it would be great!

Comment: What do `number_latest_added` and `latest` do?

Comment: Add a break; statement after first echo, edit your post and print output above.

Comment: A suggestion, when printing HTML like this, wrap it in single quotes instead so you don't need to escape all double quotes. It will make it much more readable. Example: `echo '<a class="example-image" href="' . $latest . '" ...`. It's just my preference anyway.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for the tip man ! didn't realize you could do it that way =)

Comment: @chris85 `latest($n)` goes and gets the $n latest path in my database(sorted database by date added)

 `number_latest_added` is a quick function that returns how many paths i have in my databse.

Comment: In the future it'd be good to include custom functions that are being used.

Comment: @chris85 Okey, i just assumed it would be unreleavent information.
Never assume i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the function `latest`?  From what you are saying I am guessing it is something like:

```
function latest($number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

and you need something like:

```
function latest($number) {
    return $number;
}
```

Comment: the function `latest` returns an image path; so something like ''image/art/e8cf4c5b49.jpg" a string

Comment: It works !! Thanks a lot for the help =) 
it makes sense now but i would never have seen that  by myself =) or atleast not until a silly amount of time !
Thanks again man !!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you turn on error reporting  `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

In addition to that, php automatically parses variables to string, if your inside double quotes.

Example:

```
$var = "hello"
echo "$var world" //prints hello world
```

Your problem is that latest($n) doesn't return anything printable, you can find that out by simply echo'ing the value itself.

Comment: error reporting was On 
And i did know php parses automatically variables to string, just wasn't sure because it wasn't working :S
Dave found the problem so it's all good, but thanks for the assistance man !